# AngularJS Flot align labels

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css, flot

In a web app I'm using flot.js for a chart. In the same index, there may be two or more columns. Each one, at the top, will have a column value label.
The problem is that all labels are aligned with the index. How can I align the labels with the corresponding column?

```
data: myData,
dataLabels: {
    show: true
},
bars: {
   show: true,
   barWidth: .3,
   fill: true,
   lineWidth: 0,
   order: 1,
   fillColor: CUSTOM_COLOR
}
```

This is the function in the flot directive that makes the labels:

```
let drawDataLabels = (plot: any) => {
    if(plot 
      && scope.options.dataLabels 
      && scope.options.dataLabels.show) {
      plot.getPlaceholder().children(".flot-data-label").remove();

      for (let el of plot.getData()) {
        if (el.datapoints 
          && el.datapoints.points 
          && el.datapoints.points.length > 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < el.datapoints.points.length; i += el.datapoints.pointsize) {
              let data = el.datapoints.points.slice(i, i + el.datapoints.pointsize);
              if (data[1]) {
                let offset = plot.pointOffset({ x: data[0], y: data[1] });
                let cssClass = scope.options.dataLabels.css && scope.options.dataLabels.css.class ? scope.options.dataLabels.css.class : "";
                let dataLabelDiv = $('<div class="flot-data-label ' + cssClass + '"><span>' + data[1] + '</span></div>');
                dataLabelDiv.css({
                  position: 'absolute',
                  left: offset.left,
                  top: offset.top,
                  color: el.bars.fillColor
                }).appendTo(plotArea);
                let dataLabelDivSpan = $(dataLabelDiv.children()[0]);
                dataLabelDivSpan.css({
                  position: 'relative',
                  left: - dataLabelDiv.width() / 2,
                  top: - dataLabelDiv.height() - 1
                });
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the current result:

[image]

and this is what is expected:

[image]

This is a live example, it is not all my code but the concept is the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/z4jrubmq/1/

Comment: can you create a fiddle with this issue??

Comment: can we check your result live so we can clearly understand the issue.?

Comment: I made this one, it's a bit different but it has the same concept: http://jsfiddle.net/z4jrubmq/1/